How to perform logic on git log within the `--format` to modify the output?
I want to generate a CSV-formatted revision history of a file with the following values:

File version
Date
Change message
Author
Change type (internal category that will be defined in a git trailer such as Change_type)
Internal change record (again, this will be defined in the git commit trailer as Change_record)

The CSV headers look like this:
File version,Date,Change type,Change message,Change record,Author

If I were to use the commit SHA as the file version, it'd be fine. This works for my purposes:
git log --format="%h,%as,%-(trailers:key=Change_type,valueonly=true,separator=''),%s,%-(trailers:key=Change_record,valueonly=true,separator=''),%an" MyDocument.md

This shows up like this:
91s5ec9,2024-12-01,XYZ,Updated document Y,1234,Joe Smith

I have this mostly working with this but one issue--we can't use the commit SHA as the file version. The file will have the version defined in the front matter at the top (it'd be much simpler if we could just use the commit SHA and do away with manually updating the version number in the document but we're not there yet).
My document contains YAML front matter at the beginning like this:
title: Some title
version: 0.1.2

I can get the document version like this:
git show 91s5ec9:MyDocument.md | sed -nE 's/^version:\s*(\S+)\r?/\1/p' | head -1

Is there any way to perform the above processing--get the file contents at XYZ revision and parse out a certain value--inline during the git log? I can do it in a loop like this:
for i in $(git log --format=%H MyDocument.md); do
  VERSION=$(git show $i:MyDocument.md | sed -nE 's/^version:\s*(\S+)\r?/\1/p' | head -1)
  git log $i -1 --format="$VERSION,%as,%-(trailers:key=Change_type,valueonly=true,separator=''),%s,%-(trailers:key=Change_record,valueonly=true,separator=''),%an" MyDocument.md
done

This would work but I'd prefer if I can do all the processing inline with a single git log instead of looping and running git log repeatedly for however many documents & however many commits there may be.
I'm picturing something like this:
git log --format="%(git show %h:MyDocument.md | sed -nE 's/^version:\s*(\S+)\r?/\1/p' | head -1),%as,%-(trailers:key=Change_type,valueonly=true,separator=''),%s,%-(trailers:key=Change_record,valueonly=true,separator=''),%an" MyDocument.md

Is this possible or should I just stick with the for loop? Or are there other ways this can be refined/made more efficient?

I think that a loop is a good solution, there is also git rebase --exec but you'd have to manually filter the commits that touched MyDocument.md.

Hmm, there's also an interesting option --ext-diff, maybe it could be abused to run a command on each commit

I don't know of a way to do things more directly than your for loop.
